# Arranging a multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array, sorting

I have a PHP array that looks like this: http://pastie.org/1346063 (see pastie for array example)

What I want to do is re-sort that array into another array that is sorted by each array's [votes][POINTS] sub-array numerically descending. The array with the highest [votes][POINTS] value will be the first listed in the main array.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `usort()` function we can create our own comparison function:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if($a['votes']['POINTS'] == $b['votes']['POINTS']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['votes']['POINTS'] < $b['votes']['POINTS']) ? 1 : -1;
}

usort($array, 'cmp');
```

**Results:**

Using test data with a similar structure as yours:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [votes] => Array
                (
                    [UP] => 1
                    [DOWN] => 0
                    [POINTS] => 5
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [votes] => Array
                (
                    [UP] => 1
                    [DOWN] => 0
                    [POINTS] => 4
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [votes] => Array
                (
                    [UP] => 1
                    [DOWN] => 0
                    [POINTS] => 2
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [votes] => Array
                (
                    [UP] => 1
                    [DOWN] => 0
                    [POINTS] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: That function you gave me does not seem to work. I'm not sure if it is CodeIgniter, or something within the function. I tried loading that function as a plugin, and it seems to error out. I'm not sure what the error is because my errors aren't showing. The only time the error occures is when calling upon the usort function with cmp.

Comment: The function itself works. I'm not very familiar with CI, however, you should be able to create this function within your Model and simply call it. CI might log all errors by default, might be worth checking your `application/logs` or wherever the logs are located.

Comment: @DevNull Be sure to NOT assign the return value from `usort` back to `$array`! `usort` alters the input array, it doesn't return the sorted array.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:-

Suppose, your array is stored in a variable named **$data**

You can simply sort your multi-dimensional array with [array_multisort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

```
foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
    $points[$key]  = $row['votes']['points'];
}

// Sort the data with points descending
array_multisort($points, SORT_DESC, $data);
```

Hope this helps.